# calling action creators on state/props change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx, react-proptypes

Parent Component:

```
{this.state.Child2 ? (
  <Child2 Colorvalue={this.state.activeColor} somename={this.state.name} />
) : (
  <Child1 somename={this.state.name} Colorvalue={this.state.activeColor} />
)}
```

both in child1 & child2 components i have added a call to actioncreator (api call) to get some info - in ComponentWillMount method - everything works fine..

```
this.props.fetchData(somename, Colorvalue);
```

Now I need to update both children if Colorvalue changes on parent..I should call actioncreator with the new `'Colorvalue'`
Should I have another call in update/receive props method of both the child components? How to handle this case.?

In each Child component there will be 2 calls to actionCreators if I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dipatch the API call `this.props.fetchData(...)` in the parent. Then update `this.state.activeColor` in parent. Now pass that value as props to `Child1` or `Child2`.

Inside your child components, since you're dispatching the action in `ComponentWillMount`, there **won't** happen a new API call in them when you supply new props from parent.

If you want to update internal states (if any) of the child components upon receiving the new props, you may use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`.

---

#### **UPDATE:**

`Child1` and `Child2` receives new color from parent via props.
So if you want to trigger the API call on receiving new props, dispatch `this.props.fetchData(...)` inside `componentWillReceiveProps` of child components.

hope you are using ES6 classes:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.Colorvalue !== nextProps.Colorvalue) {
        this.props.fetchData(this.props.somename, nextProps.Colorvalue);
    }
}
```

also I am assuming you have mapped the action creator `fetchData` as props to your child components using `connect`.

Comment: but I want a new call when ever the color changes in both the children..is there any way I can do this by not making use of {connect} and actioncreator calls inside parent?

Comment: are you using `connect` on your child components?

Comment: yea, I am using connect in both the child components, but not on parent...